# Why can't I write a PNG file correctly on Windows with Java from a downloaded source?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a PNG file from a image retrieved from the web.  This is what I'm doing (the http code and IOUtils magic are both from Apache):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(new URI("http://tinyurl.com/krb43g"));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(entity.getContent());
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("Picture", ".png");
    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
    IOUtils.write(data, writer);
    writer.close();
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32.exe \"C:\\Program Files (x86)" +
            "\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\", ImageView_Fullscreen "
            + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

The image comes out corrupted in some way and Windows cannot display it.  Am I doing something wrong with the write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a Writer when you should be using an OutputStream.  Try replacing the lines that involve a Writer with the following:

```
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
IOUtils.write(data, stream);
stream.close();
```

Comment: @HenryTyler: Just to add to this answer, `Writer` is for writing *character streams*, not *byte streams*: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html